# Javascript array filter by checking multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as:

```
var arr = 
[
    {
        "id":3,
        "first_name":"Laila",
        "last_name":"McCaine",
        "gender":"female",      
        "populations":[{"population_name":"Heart failure"}, {"population_name":"AMI"}],
        "score": 55.0
    },
    {
        "id":5,     
        "first_name":"Riva",
        "last_name":"Rontgen",
        "gender":"female",
        "populations":[{"population_name":"Pnumonia"}],
        "score": 85.0
    },
    {
        "id":8,
        "first_name":"Emily",   
        "last_name":"Rosewood",
        "gender":"female",  
        "populations":[],
        "score": 25.0
    }
];
```

and variables :

```
var score='';
var population='';
var status = '';
```

I want to use array `filter` function with `and` conditions such as 
Get records having `score` less than 40, `status` = 1 and `population_name` as "heart failure".

The problem is, given 3 variables are `dynamic` and `filter` should not be applied if its value is ''.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to apply array filter automatically every time the array gets modified?

Comment: Well, it's quite straight-forward to check whether the filters are `""`; what have you tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this:

```
arr.filter(function(item) {
    var ok = true;

    if (score !== '') {
        ok = item.score < score;
    }

    if (ok && population !== '') {
        // check it
        ok = item.populations.map(function() {return item.population_name;}).indexOf(population) > -1;
    }

    if (ok && status !== '') {
        // check status
    }

    return ok;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = 
[
    {
        "id":3,
        "status": 1,
        "first_name":"Laila",
        "last_name":"McCaine",
        "gender":"female",      
        "populations":[{"population_name":"Heart failure"}, {"population_name":"AMI"}],
        "score": 55.0
    },
    {
        "id":5,   
        "status": 1,
        "first_name":"Riva",
        "last_name":"Rontgen",
        "gender":"female",
        "populations":[{"population_name":"Pnumonia"}],
        "score": 85.0
    },
    {
        "id":8,
        "status": 0,
        "first_name":"Emily",   
        "last_name":"Rosewood",
        "gender":"female",  
        "populations":[],
        "score": 25.0
    }
];

function filterRecords( arr ){
  return arr.filter(function( record ){
    return record.score > 40 && record.status && (record.populations.filter(function( population ){
      return population.population_name == 'Heart failure';
    })).length;
  });
}

console.log( filterRecords( arr ) );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```